# Rectangular edges for custom SeekBar

Tags: android, customization, seekbar

I have customize the **SeekBar** using a **LayeredDrawable**, The drawable works fine, but the drawable used as a background becomes rounded at the corners (Both the corner, here only the right end is shown. When the thumb is moved to the extreme left, the left corner is also rounded. Note: The original image is rectangular). How do I make it rectangular?

[image]

Here is my LayerdDrawable xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/progress_bg" />
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/progress" />
    </clip>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Go And Try this one, 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804259/removing-rounded-edges-of-a-customized-seekbar/15808527#15808527'.

Answer (score 4):

You can extract information from [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/be3fed0b4f766cc) (related) question posted on android-developers Google Group. Pay attention to `<corners android:radius="5dip" />`. That's the parameter you'll need to change.

UPDATE: What the heck, I'll just post some code. = )

```
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="0dip" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

You might need to do the same thing with `secondaryProgress` and so on.