# Seekbar rectangular corners

Tags: android-layout

I have a situation similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922352/rectangular-edges-for-custom-seekbar), however, the method supposed there isn't working for me. I've tried different variation with  tag but nothing has helped so far.

Here's my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="20"
        android:progress="0"
        android:secondaryProgress="0"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress" />
</LinearLayout>
```

drawable-mdpi/seekbar_progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
          android:drawable="@drawable/passive_progress">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/active_progress">
        <clip>
           <shape>
               <corners android:radius="0dp" />
           </shape>
       </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Go And Try this one, 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804259/removing-rounded-edges-of-a-customized-seekbar/15808527#15808527'.