# Android SeekBar rounded corner

Tags: android, layout, seekbar

I have this `SeekBar` in my `XML`:

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/player_seek_bar_volume"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="14dp"
        android:paddingRight="14dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar"
        android:thumb="@drawable/scrubber_control" />
```

It is possible to add rounded corner to `SeekBar` in Androdid?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804259/removing-rounded-edges-of-a-customized-seekbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I think this would help you

http://blog.mediarain.com/2011/04/android-custom-progressbar-with-rounded-corners/

or this

http://device-manual.blogspot.in/2012/12/perform-custom-progressbar-android.html

Comment: Both links are dead.